# WPF ImageBrush remove "blurred dropshadow"

Tags: wpf

For some reason, my ImageBrush background as an odd blurry drop shadow to it.

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource SeamlessBtn}" Width="30" Height="30" Click="ToggleTheme"
                            BorderBrush="Transparent" Margin="10,10,105,408" Foreground="Transparent">
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush x:Name="BrightSwitch" ImageSource="/Images/BootstrapIcons-MoonFill.png"/>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
```

[image]

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" TargetType="Button" 
           x:Key="SeamlessBtn">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Edit: I am using materialDesignTheme

Comment: Sure that this is not in the PNG?

Comment: Yes, because when I use the Image Tag with that png, it does not happen and I checked the png itself.

Comment: Try `<Button ... RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor">`

Comment: The geometry is here https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/moon-fill/   I would suggest a path as content of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the geometry is readily available.

https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/moon-fill/

I would suggest trying that.

I put such geometries in a resource dictionary I merge in app.xaml but that could be anywhere in scope of your button instead:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Geometry x:Key="MoonGeometry">
        M6 .278a.768.768 0 0 1 .08.858 7.208 7.208 0 0 0-.878 3.46c0 4.021 3.278 7.277 7.318 7.277.527 0 1.04-.055 1.533-.16a.787.787 0 0 1 .81.316.733.733 0 0 1-.031.893A8.349 8.349 0 0 1 8.344 16C3.734 16 0 12.286 0 7.71 0 4.266 2.114 1.312 5.124.06A.752.752 0 0 1 6 .278z        
    </Geometry>
</Window.Resources>
```

Since that's seems to be the only thing you have in your button you can just make it content. In just a plain button:

```
    <Button>
        <Path Data="{StaticResource MoonGeometry}" 
              Fill="Black" 
              Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Button>
```

Or if you particularly wanted a background and brush:

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Background>
            <DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black"
                                     Geometry="{StaticResource MoonGeometry}"/>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

Either approach gives you a sharp picture because it's using vectors.

[image]

Comment: It works now, but how would I make the image be as large as the button. Because If I scale down the button, the image disappears. (I basically need Geometry that works like a button=

Comment: My button and that moon shape fill a grid which fill the entire window in my markup above. The stretch setting controls that. Uniform retains proportions. Fill ignores proportions.